# How can I get value from string?

Tags: curl, json

I have this curl output below:

```
{
    "code": "Ok",
    "routes": [{
        "geometry": "mlbj@qsp}VlEi@hAvHRCiKyr@gBkK`MmBN`AcC^QaA}GbAm@PRx@lDzUu@L?V",
        "legs": [{
            "steps": [],
            "summary": "",
            "weight": 356.9,
            "duration": 356.9,
            "distance": 2567.6
        }],
        "weight_name": "routability",
        "weight": 356.9,
        "duration": 356.9,
        "distance": 2567.6
    }],
    "waypoints": [{
        "hint": "FowshhuMLIYyAAAAfAAAAF0BAAAAAAAAgPWmQVj0TEJA9hBDAAAAADIAAAB8AAAAXQEAAAAAAADvOAAA2WB8B2bEawDqYHwHasRrAAcAfwpAAACy",
        "distance": 1.929525,
        "name": "",
        "location": [125.591769, 7.06263]
    }, {
        "hint": "w1ACh____38VAAAALAAAAAgAAABXAAAAwBUMQdyhGkH5DFdA6ToRQhUAAAAsAAAACAAAAFcAAADvOAAAbXN8B9rFawB6c3wHkcVrAAEAPxBAAACy",
        "distance": 8.199417,
        "name": "",
        "location": [125.596525, 7.063002]
    }]
}
```

I want to get the values of `duration` and `distance` from the `legs` section of `routes`. In this example, that would be `356.9` and `2567.6` respectively.

```
 "code": "Ok",
    "routes": [{
        "geometry": "mlbj@qsp}VlEi@hAvHRCiKyr@gBkK`MmBN`AcC^QaA}GbAm@PRx@lDzUu@L?V",
        "legs": [{
            "steps": [],
            "summary": "",
            "weight": 356.9,
            "duration": 356.9,
            "distance": 2567.6
```

I just know how to execute curl script, but I don't know how to extract values needed from it, so I ask for your help.

Comment: How can we know which `duration` value you want? Will it always be the first one found? Will you have the name of the `geometry` (in this case `mlbj@qsp}VlEi@hAvHRCiKyr@gBkK`MmBN`AcC^QaA}GbAm@PRx@lDzUu@L?V`?)

Comment: How do you want the results? `jq -r '.routes[0].legs[0] | {duration, distance}'` will get you a JSON block

Comment: terdon, yes it will be on geometry section

Comment: roaima, where do you execute jq - r?   I would like to get the value in html or php file.

Comment: @terdon, the values is always under the ROUTES then LEGS section.

Comment: @genesislubrigas are you saving the curl output to a file? If so then you should use what roaima said: `jq -r '.routes[0].legs[0] | {duration, distance}' < curl_output.txt`. If you are using directly `curl` then you should use: `curl --silent your_url ... | jq -r '.routes[0].legs[0] | {duration, distance}'`

Comment: genesis lubrigas, [you asked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721186/how-can-i-extract-value-from-curl-output#comment1367447_721186), "_where do you execute `jq - r`_" - we really need a response to the [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721186/how-can-i-extract-value-from-curl-output#comment1367378_721186) seeking clarification, "_How do you want the results?_". Specifically, is JSON sufficient or do you want two plain numbers on separate rows, or whitespace separated values on one line, or ...? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Answer (score 3):

The following `jq` command would extract each `duration` and `distance` value pair in the `legs` array as two tab-delimited fields.  This would be done for all entries in the `routes` array.

```bash
jq -r '.routes[].legs | map([.duration, .distance]|@tsv)[]'
```

You would typically pipe the output of `curl` into this command:

```bash
curl -s '...some URL...' | jq -r '...as above...'
```

Given the data in the question, this would generate

```
356.9   2567.6
```

You would obviously then parse the generated list of duration+distance pairs with some other command, like `awk`, depending on what you need to do with this data.

Comment: Hello to all.  Thank you so much for all your replies.  I have tried all your suggestions to practice.